# I want to create an image modal with working next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am trying to create a modal with an image tag inside that will show the corresponding image src tag of a list of images on a page. I am not sure how to get the image index of the selected image and increment and decrement the index and it will change the src attribute to the corresponding src. I linked what I have my code below but I am not sure what to do from there. Can someone please help me thank you.

```js
const galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll(".img-grid")
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal")
let newImg

for (i=0; i<galleryImages.length; i++) {
    galleryImages[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {

        console.log(galleryImages[i])

        modal.classList.add("active")
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"

        var createImg = document.createElement("img")
        createImg.classList = "createdImg"

        newImg = modal.appendChild(createImg)

        newImg.src = e.target.src

        console.log(e.target.src)

        return newImg

    })
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="grid hookah">
                <div class="img-grid special">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-2.JPG" alt="hookah-2">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid special">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-3.JPG" alt="hookah-3">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-1.jpg" alt="hookah-1">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-4.JPG" alt="hookah-4">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid left">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-5.JPG" alt="hookah-5">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid left">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-6.JPG" alt="hookah-6">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-1.JPG" alt="Shelf-1">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-2.JPG" alt="shelf-2">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-3.JPG" alt="shelf-3">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-4.JPG" alt="shelf-4">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-5.JPG" alt="shelf-5">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-6.JPG" alt="shelf-6">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-7.JPG" alt="shelf-7">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-8.JPG" alt="shelf-8">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I first am providing a demonstration of what you are having an issue with. You are changing the source attribute of `newImg` where that is not the img element. You want to change the src attribute of `createImg` instead.

```js
const galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll(".img-grid")
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal")
let newImg

for (i=0; i<galleryImages.length; i++) {
    galleryImages[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {

        console.log(galleryImages[i])

        modal.classList.add("active")
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"

        var createImg = document.createElement("img")
        createImg.classList = "createdImg"

        newImg = modal.appendChild(createImg)

        //newImg.src = e.target.src
        createImg.src = e.target.src

        console.log(e.target.src)

        return newImg

    });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="grid hookah">
                <div class="img-grid special">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-2.JPG" alt="hookah-2">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid special">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-3.JPG" alt="hookah-3">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-1.jpg" alt="hookah-1">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-4.JPG" alt="hookah-4">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid left">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-5.JPG" alt="hookah-5">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid left">
                    <img src="./images/hookah-6.JPG" alt="hookah-6">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-1.JPG" alt="Shelf-1">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-2.JPG" alt="shelf-2">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-3.JPG" alt="shelf-3">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-4.JPG" alt="shelf-4">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-5.JPG" alt="shelf-5">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-6.JPG" alt="shelf-6">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-7.JPG" alt="shelf-7">
                </div>
                <div class="img-grid">
                    <img src="./images/shelf-8.JPG" alt="shelf-8">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I include that demonstration as a solution to your answer, in case there are other aspects of your project restricting the structure of your code. I am also providing a demonstration of how I would solve this issue.

```js
const galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll(".img-grid img")
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal")

modal.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => modal.classList.remove("active")
);

galleryImages.forEach(
  img => img.addEventListener("click", imgClicked)
);
function imgClicked(e) {
  const imgHtml = e.target.outerHTML;
  modal.innerHTML = imgHtml;
  modal.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
  display: none;
}

.modal.active{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid hookah">
        <div class="img-grid special">
            <img src="./images/hookah-2.JPG" alt="hookah-2">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid special">
            <img src="./images/hookah-3.JPG" alt="hookah-3">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/hookah-1.jpg" alt="hookah-1">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/hookah-4.JPG" alt="hookah-4">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid left">
            <img src="./images/hookah-5.JPG" alt="hookah-5">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid left">
            <img src="./images/hookah-6.JPG" alt="hookah-6">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/shelf-1.JPG" alt="Shelf-1">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/shelf-2.JPG" alt="shelf-2">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/shelf-3.JPG" alt="shelf-3">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/shelf-4.JPG" alt="shelf-4">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/shelf-5.JPG" alt="shelf-5">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/shelf-6.JPG" alt="shelf-6">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/shelf-7.JPG" alt="shelf-7">
        </div>
        <div class="img-grid">
            <img src="./images/shelf-8.JPG" alt="shelf-8">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
    </div>
</div>
```

In an actual project I might create the image element and destroy it as the modal is closed. However, for a quick snippet I believe this demonstrates the intent clearly. Hopefully this helps!